# Создание полноценных приложений (windows)

Tags: книги

После изучения языков программирования (*Паскаль*, потом *С++*) я задался вопросом:

> А что же дальше? Когда я смогу делать то, что делают программисты на
>   своей работе...Надо же мне как-то привыкать, по-скольку хочу поступить в
>   институт Программной инженерии.

И вот сел я как-то, начал гуглить, что к чему... Нашёл большой объём ненужной мне информации. Много читал о **Qt**, **WinAPI** и другом, но толком не понял, что мне подойдёт.

Я бы хотел начать с создания просто калькулятора, допустим. Понимаю, что его можно сделать где-угодно, а проекты по-сложнее?

Вообщем, не хочу много писать...Посоветуйте пожалуйста литературу (видео, статьи) о создании приложений (не кроссплатформенных), буду очень рад!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Вообщем, не хочу много писать...Посоветуйте пожалуйста литературу (видео, статьи) о создании приложений (не кроссплатформенных), буду очень рад!

Не нужно бояться "кроссплатформенности". Никто ведь не принуждает.

И момент второй. Если С++ уже изучен на более-менее приемлемом уровне, лучше всего попробовать посмотреть примеры, попробовать осознать там написанное. Например тут: [`http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/all-examples.html`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/all-examples.html)

И только потом, когда появятся вопросы типа "а что за модель, что за представления, что за сигналы" - поискать инфу в сети. Не нужно книжки, оч мало достойных книжек без воды. А вот небольшие, лаконичные **тематические** статьи помогут и время сэкономить, и знания получить.

Comment: `Не нужно книжки, оч мало достойных книжек без воды` – категорически не согласен. Книги, как минимум, дают базу, без которой двигаться дальше не получится. Чтение статей без базы – занятие бессмысленное. Хорошо хоть про видео-уроки не упомянули.

Comment: Я как раз не хотел вникать в ""а что за модель, что за представления, что за сигналы"", т.к. думал, что это не популярно и т.д.

Comment: @goodalien1125, зря думали. Многие библиотеки, фрэймворки это не просто используют, а используют не иначе как фундамент построения приложений. И Qt так же. Ознакомьтесь - https://habrahabr.ru/post/215605/

Comment: @post_zeew , никто ведь не запрещает - советуйте конкретную важную и нужную книжку.

Comment: @Majestio, Последний раз я использовал C/C++ и QT курсе на втором или на третьем университета, а было это довольно давно, поэтому что-то конкретное я не посоветую. Мой комментарий относился к `Не нужно книжки`. Я уверен, что для вещей, подобных QT, существуют хорошие книги. Изучение чего-то должно начинаться с базы, которая очень хорошо описана в книгах. Кстати, из-за `Не нужно книжки` на SO и появляются вопросы вроде: "Я android-программист, делаю клиент-серверную игру, объясните мне, чем отличается `int` от `Integer`".

Comment: У каждого своя "история". Когда-то и я купил книгу по Qt 4.7. Мало того, что старье (на то время уже 5 бета выходила), так лирики было 4 к 1. Я не утверждаю, что "книжки - зло". Достойных мало. Издателям быстрее бы в печать отдать. А вот начав изучать живые примеры - быстренько освоился в том, что я не знаю. И быстренько нашел где почитать. Ну а про видеокурсы - это отдельный разговор))) Особенно касается вебинаров. Нет, чтобы ведущему подготовится. Так нет - надо заставить ведро пропкорна слушателя употребить, пока ведущий свой код доформатирует, и наконец-таки выдаст мысль)))

Comment: "Полноценное" не кроссплатформенное Windows приложение обычно пишут на C# в  Visual Studio. А "проекты посложнее" на Java + Web- интерфейс пользователя.

Comment: Святая, божественная, наивность! )))